Hyper-V Ubuntu broken NIC
so it happened that I have upgraded my machine from Intel core i5 to Ryzen 5 9600X and my Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V protested about this change :-] It works, but NIC does not get an ip address. I removed/added it back and still it says wired disconnected. Any idea how to restore it?
vitas@vitas-Ubuntu:~$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:00:64:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:29:27:1d:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever


In Hyper-V, is the Ubuntu VM using the "Default Switch" from the "Virtual Switch Manager"?

Now there is an error message: the network adapter is configured to a switch which no longer exists or a resource pool that has been deleted or renamed.

so the problem was that Hyper-V somehow changed the virtual switch configuration to a PCIe NIC which was removed from the PC already. It was not used before, so I don't know why, but anyway configuring virtual switch to a proper onboard NIC fixed the problem.
